# select rows in tibble by a random interval

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm trying take a sequence of dates--and starting with the first date--select subsequent dates by a random number generated from a normal distribution. At the moment I have code that selects the row number by a random number, but it uses the same number every time. In this example, it selects a row every 12 days:

```
set.seed(123)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

start_date <- as.Date('2018-03-01')
end_date <- as.Date('2018-07-01')

seq_dates <- seq(ymd(start_date), ymd(end_date), by='1 days')

seq_dates <- seq_dates %>%
  as.tibble()
seq_dates

seq_dates %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% round(rnorm(n=1, mean=14, sd=3), 0) == 1)
```

Is there a way I can do this with dplyr, but select a row from the start date at a random interval every time? So from 2018-03-01 the next date might be 12 days later, then 14 days later, then 19 days later, etc?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(10) 
n <- rnorm(50, 14, 3)
rows <- cumsum(round(n, 0))
diff(rows) # random ~normal increments used when selecting your rows
#  [1] 13 10 12 15 15 10 13  9 13 17 16 13 17 16 14 11 13 17 15 12  7 12  8 10 13 12 11 14 13  8 14 17
# [33] 15 10 10 15  9 13 12 17 12 12 17 11 14 15 13 12 16

seq_dates %>% 
  slice(rows[rows <= n()])
# # A tibble: 9 x 1
#   value     
#   <date>    
# 1 2018-03-14
# 2 2018-03-27
# 3 2018-04-06
# 4 2018-04-18
# 5 2018-05-03
# 6 2018-05-18
# 7 2018-05-28
# 8 2018-06-10
# 9 2018-06-19
```